# Javascript / xHTML need to grab the xml:lang

Tags: javascript, xml, xhtml

Doing a german site, and have a JS alert to say you havn't completed all the required fields.

So want to get the langage of the HTMLpage

Here's the HTML;

```
<html xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  ...
</html>
```

This is my JS.... it seems to error and not alert at all with the lang bits...

How do it get the xml:lang attribute?

```
var lang = document.getElementByTagname("html").attributes.getNamedItem("xml:lang").value;
                alert("You must complete all the required information");
                alert(lang);
```

Comment: `document.getElementByTagname()` doesn't exist, it should be `document.getElementsByTagName()`, and it returns an array. The rest of the code doesn't seem to work in this case either. My answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an xml:lang attribute and not a lang attribute, you aren't writing [HTML Compatible XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_7), therefore:

```
var htmls = document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html');
var html = htmls[0];
var lang = html.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'lang');.
```

(OK, this is slightly tongue in cheek. You should probably fix your markup to conform to the compatibility guidelines instead. Then just

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].lang
```

)

Comment: Yeh cheers, completly missed it... @lang is now in there. I feel school boy. lol

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('xml:lang');
```